# Copy and unarchive Ansible Module

Tags: ansible

I tried below ansible tasks  with copy and unarchive modules and facing error

```
- name: find and archive
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: find the file
      copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "/home/ec2-user/bb"
        remote_src: yes
      with_fileglob:
        - "/home/ec2-user/aa/Data*"
      register: result
    - name: show the result file path
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
    - name: extract file
      unarchive:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: /home/ec2-user/cc/
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
```

the error is:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are registering the output of the `copy` module in the `result` variable. When the copy module runs in a loop, it returns a `results` key that contains each item of the loop.

The copy module does not have a `files` return value. The return values are [listed here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#return-values). What you want to use is the `dest` value.  The `dest` value is where you copied the file using the `copy` module, that will become your `src` value for the `unarchive` module.

You can adjust your playbook to use those variables like this:

```yaml
- name: find and archive
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: find the file
      copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "/home/ec2-user/bb"
        remote_src: yes
      with_fileglob:
        - "/home/ec2-user/aa/Data*"
      register: result
    - name: show the result file path
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.dest }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
    - name: extract file
      unarchive:
        src: "{{ item.dest }}"
        dest: /home/ec2-user/cc/
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
```